# The method to copy a html <div> for inserting into a database include value of input text

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want copy a content div with jQuery `clone()` and include value input text. Is this the right method, or if this is not, what is the right method?

Comment: clone is meant to create an element object with the same properties as the one it is clone with. If you want to copy the contents ( html ) of the div , then just do $('div').html()

Comment: can you provide more details of what you are trying to do? This one line description seems too vague.

Comment: I have a table with a lot input text and  I want store in a database the code html with value inputs

Answer (score 0):

JQuery clone is inappropriate in this case because it's use to create a DOM of the selected element. And it stores the object not the readable content.

but to get the contents inside selector, JQuery has two methods 
1. `text()` 
2. `html()`

`text()` is used to get only textual content of the selector not html part of it.
`html()` is used to get both textual and html content, i meant to say everything inside a selector.